# Android MediaPlayer pause

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

The problem I am having at the moment is that my pause is not always working.
What I have is an MediaPlayer in main activity that is operated via ActionBarSherlock and onClick listeners. MediaPlayer is using ArrayList with URLs of MP3 files(some of them 1sec long).

Pause code:

```
       if (player.isPlaying()) {
            if (player != null) {
                player.pause();
                swapPlayIcon(1);
                isPaused = true;
                pauseMenuButt.setVisible(false);
                playMenuButt.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

swapPlayIcon(int) handles only visibility and drawable swaps.

Start code:

```
    Iterator<Uri> iterUri = tracks.iterator();
    while (iterUri.hasNext()) {
        Uri tmpUri = iterUri.next();
        try {
            player.reset();
            player.setDataSource(String.valueOf(tmpUri));
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

After more testing I have found out that the problem appear in "in between" state.

What I mean is that when my MP3 file is 2sec long and I click pause its not stopping becouse it just have ended reading one file and now moved on to the next one.

I have added:

```
      } else {
          pauseLocked = true;
      }
```

to pause if statment and it does not land in it at all while testing. 
So im not sure about the "in between" problem that I have found out previously.

Comment: Not sure what the answer is, but it's important to note that you've got some potential for a NullPointerException in that first block... you say if(player.isPlaying()) and THEN check for player!=null. If player was null, you would have seen a NPE on the call to player.isPlaying(). You should either move the null check out of the  isPlaying() if statement, or remove it completely.

Comment: yea indeed you're right :>

Comment: First off playback is not blocking so you will cycle through media as fast as the player can prepare each media stream from your url.  Second, are you on [4.4 and are you trying to play HLSs](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63346&q=HLS&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)?

Comment: No im testing it on 4.3 and 4.2. And MP3 files are on the device.

Comment: @JakubW do you understand the first issue?  Finally, you are correct that you cannot perform the pause operation while the media player is preparing, but you will never ever be able to do that because you're using the blocking version of prepare(), so that's why the else branch of your block is not getting hit.

Comment: Yea I understand the first issue but how should I block it then?
Becouse at the moment everything is working for me just fine but the only problem that occur is the pause issue.

Comment: @JakubW it's probably "working" because your clips are so short.  You don't want to block it but to answer the question I think you are trying to ask, you need to add an OnCompletionListener to the MediaPlayer and only start the next url once that callback gets hit.

Comment: I see where the missunderstanding is now.
The array list here is a list of aditional elements that Object contains. But normally I do have onCompletionListener that handles end of the sound readings. So it would be broken on the objects that have < 1 urls. But it not working on the objects with 1 url too.

Comment: @JakubW that's not the issue.

Comment: The main loop is reccurent use of Playable objects that is handled in Fragment. The Fragment implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener and when sound is read it moves to the next Playable element in ArrayList.
The start code above is play() method inside Playable.

Comment: Regardless of whether you have a list of "playable" objects, each object contains a list of urls and for those urls you're still blocking the UI thread for each one of those playable objects.  Your pause button will work for the last url in each playable object, then.

Answer (score 1):

Your *pause* button is not working because there's no way for its message to ever reach the MediaPlayer until you've started the last URL.  You are entirely blocking the thread your MediaPlayer is running on (I'm assuming it's the UI thread since the MediaPlayer is in your main activity).  If you're creating your MediaPlayer on the same thread as your UI, you should use the asynchronous version of prepare: prepareAsync.  You need to respond once you receive the onMediaPrepared callback and then start the media.  Once that happens you must do nothing and wait for the media to finish, only then should you load another url.

Comment: Yeah media playback can be pretty confusing to get a grasp on.  The media player itself is a complex state machine and your backing activity needs to manage all those states properly.  Something seemingly simple like looping though audio streams will come out quite complex.  Good luck!